# Querying a view using multiple keys

Tags: view, couchbase

Given the following view for the gamesim-sample example:

```
function (doc, meta) {
    if (doc.jsonType == "player" && doc.experience) {
       emit([doc.experience,meta.id], doc.id);
    }
}
```

I would like to Query the leaderboard for users who only belong to specific group (the grouping data is maintained in an external system).

For e.g. if the view has users "orange","purple","green","blue" and "red" I would like the leaderboard to give me the rankings of only "orange" and "purple" without having to query their respective current experience points.

```
...view/leaderboard?keys=[[null,"orange"],[null,"purple"]
```

The following works fine, but it requires additional queries to find the experience point of "orange" and "purple" beforehand. However, this does not scale for obvious reasons.

```
...view/leaderboard?keys=[[1,"orange"],[5,"purple"]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you simply reverse the order of your key array? Also, it is redundant to emit the doc Id. Better to emit null.

Comment: I need to order the results using experience to get the ranking. I don't see how reversing the order in the key would lead to a solution. You are correct, it is redundant to emit the doc Id, this is just an example I am working on.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the issue. Indexes are sorted on first element, then second element, and so on. Can you give an example of the output you would like to see that is a little more clear?

Comment: I want the output to be sorted by the first element(doc.experience) and filtered by the second element (doc.id): `{"total_rows":2,"rows":[
{"id":"orange","key":[1,"orange"],"value":null},
{"id":"purple","key":[5,"purple"],"value":null}]`

Comment: Can you write the equivalent sql query?

Comment: Thanks for the persistence! :) `select * from leaderboard where id in ('orange','purple') order by experience;`

Comment: Does `the grouping data is maintained in an external system` mean that `orange` is not coded anywhere on the document in your bucket?

Answer (score 0):

#### Some NoSql vs. SQL Background

First, you have to remember that specifically with Couchbase, the advantage is the super-fast storage and retrieval of records.  Indicies were added later, as a way to make storage a little more useful and less error-prone (think of them more as an automated inventory) and their design really constrains you to move away from SQL-style thinking. Your query above is a perfect example:

```
select * 
from leaderboard 
where id in ('orange','purple')
order by experience
```

This is a retrieval, computation, and filter all in one shot. This is exactly what NoSql databases are optimized **not** to do (and conversely, SQL databases *are*, which often makes them hopelessly complex, but that is another topic).

So, this leads to the primary difference between a SQL vs a NoSQL database: NoSql is optimized for **storage** while SQL is optimized for **querying**. In conjunction, it causes one to adjust how one thinks about the role of the database, which in my opinion should be more the former than the latter.

The creators of Couchbase originally focused purely on the storage aspect of the database. However, storage makes a lot more sense when you know what it is you have stored, and indices were added later as a feature (originally you had to keep track of your own stuff - it was not much fun!)  They also added in `map-reduce` in a way that takes advantage of CB's ability to store and retrieve massive quantities of records simultaneously.  Neither of these features were really intended to solve complex query problems (even though this query is simple, it is a perfect example because of this).  This is the function of your *application logic*.

#### Addressing Your Specific Issue

So, now on to your question.  The query itself *appears* to be a simple one, and indeed it is. However,

```
select * from leaderboard
```

is not actually simple. It is instead a 2-layer deep query, as your definition of leaderboard implies a sorted list from largest to smallest player experience. Therefore, this query, expanded out, becomes:

```
select * from players order by experience desc
```

Couchbase supports the above natively in the index mechanism (remember, it inventories your objects), and you have accurately described in your question how to leverage views to achieve this output.  What Couchbase does not support is the third-level query, which represents your `where` clause.  Typically, a `where` in Couchbase is executed in either the view "map" definition or the index selection parameters.  You can't do it in "map" because you don't always want the same selection, and you can't do it in the index selection parameter because the index is sorted on experience level first.

#### Method 1

Let's assume that you are displaying this to a user on a web page. You can easily implement this filter client-side (or in your web service) by pulling the data as-is and throwing out values that you don't want.  Use the `limit` and `skip` parameters to ask for more as the user scrolls down (or clicks more pages, or whatever).

#### Method 2

Reverse the order of your index, and sort by "group" (aka color) first, then experience level.  Run separate queries to select the top 'N' users of each color, then merge and sort on the client side. This will take longer to load up-front but will give you a larger in-memory data set to work with if you need it for that reason.  This method may not work well if you have a very uneven distribution of categories, in which case 'N' would need to be tailored to match the statistical distribution(s) within the categories.

#### Bottom Line

One parting thought is that NoSql databases were designed to deal with highly dynamic data sets. This requires some statistical thinking, because there no longer is a single "right" answer. Some degree of inconsistency and error is to be expected (as there always is in the real world). You can't expect a NoSql database to return a perfect query result - because there is no perfection. You have to settle for "good enough" - which is often much better than what is needed anyway.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the in depth reply. I will consider these points when designing my project.